# There is any list or service where I can find the number of primes less than or equal to an specific value?

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers

The question is quite simple, I'm looking for a list of the cardinality of each set of prime numbers below an specific natural number (n), for a very big n.

Comment: "Pi function" at this page goes up to $3\cdot 10^{13}$: https://primes.utm.edu/nthprime/

Comment: @paw88789 Remember that when the exponent consists of more than one character, you need to enclose it in brackets.

Comment: @Accumulation: Yes, thanks. Fixed.

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PrimePi%5B123456789%5D)

Comment: For some values up to $10^{27}$ here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but I need a big value, at least 3 values on the exponent.